# Show the diffusion equation is a normalised distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The diffusion equation is defined to be $$P(x,t) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4D\pi t}} \exp \left(-\dfrac{x^2}{4Dt}\right),$$ where $D$ is a physical constant.

Show that the reaction diffusion equation is a normalised distribution.

I take that this means that I need to show that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x,t) \,dx = 1$$ (the sum of probabilities is $1$), which I have shown, and that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x P(x,t) \,dx = 0$$ or that the expectation is zero.

However, previous parts of the question make us show that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2} \,dx = 1.$$

Have I got the definition of the expectation wrong? Or am I trying to show the wrong thing? If so, why?

I don't think I'll need help with calculations, but if I do, I'll ask again.

Comment: By the way, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 P(x,t) \,dx = 2Dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4D \pi t}}e^{-x^2/(4Dt)}
$$
is the fundamental solution to the initial value problem,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},\quad u(x,0) = \delta (x)\,.
$$

Note the following:

1. For $\alpha>0$, [it is well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Generalizations) that

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}\,\,\mbox{ and }\,\,\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx = 0.\tag{1}
$$

2. The *r.h.s* of each equality in $(1)$ is a differentiable function of $\alpha$. In fact, by appealing to [Leibniz's integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), we see that 
   $$
   \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx = -\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}e^{-\alpha x^2}\right)\mathrm dx = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\left(~\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx\right) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha^3}}\,.
   $$
   Therefore, 
   $$
   2\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^3}{\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx = 1,\,\,\color{red}{\mbox{and not}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx = 1}.\tag{2}
   $$
3. Furthermore, as you deduced, using $\alpha = \frac{1}{4Dt}$ in both $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives, 
   $$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{4D\pi t}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{4Dt} x^2}\mathrm dx = 1,\quad\frac{1}{\sqrt{4D\pi t}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-\frac{1}{4Dt} x^2}\mathrm dx = 0,\quad\frac{1}{\sqrt{4D\pi t}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{1}{4Dt} x^2}\mathrm dx = 2Dt.
   $$

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what the problem is. But the expextation of your distribution is indeed zero, since
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4D\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}}
\end{equation}
is an odd function. Moreover
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}dx = \sqrt{4\alpha\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\alpha\pi}}x^2e^{-\alpha x^2} dx= \sqrt{4\alpha\pi}\left(\frac{1}{2\alpha}\right),
\end{equation}
where we used that the second moment of the normal$(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\alpha}})$ distribution equals $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\alpha}})^2 + 0^2$.